# markers list renders on andriod and not on ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to render a list of markers in a map using react-native-maps.

I've successfully rendered the map with `<MapView />` but for some reason, when rendering a list of markers on the map, it appears only on android and not on IOS.

The problem is while fetching the data, cause when I tried mocking the array of markers it worked correctly.

`MapviewWrapper.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import ProvidersList from "./ProvidersList";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Layout } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { mapsConfig } from "config";

const MapviewWrapper = (props) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <MapView
        style={styles.mapStyle}
        initialRegion={mapsConfig.INITIAL_REGION}
      >
        <ProvidersList />
      </MapView>
    </Layout>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
});

export default MapviewWrapper;
```

`ProvidersList.js`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { mapsConfig } from "config";
import { getProviders } from "api/wrappers/appService";

const getProvidersAsync = (setProviders) => {
  getProviders({
    Latitude: mapsConfig.INITIAL_REGION.latitude,
    Longitude: mapsConfig.INITIAL_REGION.longitude,
    Radius: 1000,
    MeasureUnit: 0,
  }).then((providers) => setProviders(providers));
};

const ProvidersList = (props) => {
  const [providers, setProviders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProvidersAsync(setProviders);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {providers.length > 0 &&
        providers.map((provider, id) => (
          <Marker
            key={id}
            coordinate={{
              longitude: provider.Location.Longitude,
              latitude: provider.Location.Latitude,
            }}
            title={provider.Title}
            description={provider.Description}
          />
        ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProvidersList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i rendered the list of markers inside a view and not a fragment.

The markers now appear on IOS aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<MapView
         ref={MapView => (this.MapView = MapView)}
         style={styles.map}
         initialRegion={this.state.region}
         loadingEnabled = {true}
         loadingIndicatorColor="#666666"
         loadingBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
         moveOnMarkerPress = {false}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         showsCompass={true}
         showsPointsOfInterest = {false}
         provider="google">
         {this.state.markers.map((marker:any)  => (  
              <MapView.Marker
                key={marker.id}
                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                title={marker.title}
                description={marker.description}
              />
         }
      </MapView>
```